# Not Found 127 Happens when I run this docker script

Tags: docker

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER En-lightenE

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir/app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

> Step 6/10 : RUN mkdir/app  ---> Running in c617a5f47b0e /bin/sh:
>   mkdir/app: not found The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir/app' returned a
>   non-zero code: 127

Comment: I made the folder already in the workdir on my computer

Comment: Can you edit the question so that the Dockerfile contents are exactly as how they appear in your file? With missing spaces and newlines, it gets difficult as there are errors in the file itself

Comment: just add a space in `RUN mkdir/app` like this `RUN mkdir /app`

Answer (score 2):

The command should be `RUN mkdir /app` but not `RUN mkdir/app`. You are missing the space.

Also, you need not run the command mkdir when you already have `WORKDIR /app`